# How to install GNU MPFR library on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, gnu, pythonanywhere, mpfr

I'm trying to install `bigfloat` and I am getting this message that seems to indicate I need the `mpfr` library first. How do I do this?
The message:

> running build_ext building 'mpfr' extension creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mpfr. c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mpfr.o mpfr.c:344:18: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory #include "mpfr.h" ^ compilation terminated. error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

I'm pretty new to python and pythonanywhere, so I don't know how to install libraries.

I tried to find how to install a library using google, and I tried to use:

```
pip install --user mpfr
```

but I get this error message:

> Collecting mpfr Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpfr (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for mpfr

Comment: What's the error message? What have you tried?

Comment: The message:running build_ext building 'mpfr' extension creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mpfr. c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mpfr.o mpfr.c:344:18: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory #include "mpfr.h" ^ compilation terminated. error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1                                                                        i'm pretty new to python and pythonanywhere so I don't know how to install libraries.

Comment: I tried to fin how to install a library using google, and I tried to use: pip install --user mpfr        but I get this error message:
Collecting mpfr
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpfr (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mpfr

Answer (score 21):

The `gmpy2` is written in C and depends on three other C libraries: GMP, MPFR, and MPC. The easiest way to ensure all the dependencies are present is to "libmpc-dev" using the standard package management tools from your Linux distribution.
For example:

```
sudo apt-get install libmpc-dev
```

Comment: For CentOS Use :  `yum install libmpc-devel`